# Top to bottom <ul> element arrangement

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-position

I'm trying to find out how I can force elements to start from the top going to the bottom.

I have searched through Stack Overflow and I can't seem to get the answer that i need. Below I explain:

Actual:

```
A--B--C--D

E--F--G--H
```

What I need:

```
A--C--E--G

B--D--F--H
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML code?

Comment: Some jQuery solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225968/how-can-i-modify-this-algorithm-which-reorders-a-ul. My answer is not necessarily the best, that `.transpose()` plugin looks good.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ewapol/1/edit

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Solution -> http://jsfiddle.net/AcdcD/

Comment: Duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923/wrapping-lists-into-columns

Answer (score 2):

This [might not work in older browsers](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn) but you can use CSS property `column-count` like this:

```css
ul {
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
}
```

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meqFJ/).