# 3 column output for IE 8 using CSS

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Using CSS (see the CSS below) it works fine in all browsers. Unfortunately as expected it does not work within IE 8. Is their an alternative way that I can get similar 3 column output for IE 8?

```
#site-map .site-map-box {  
-webkit-column-count: 3;  
-moz-column-count: 3;  
column-count: 3;  
-webkit-column-gap: 250px;  
-moz-column-gap: 250px;  
column-gap: 250px; }
```

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670983/css3-multi-column-layout-ie-workaround

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS3 columns are not supprted in IE8. You will be able to do this using `div`s however this will only be effective if your content is static.

For example:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="float:left; width:33%;">first third of content</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:33%;">second third of content</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:33%;">third third of content</div>
</div>
```

For dynamic content you will have to use javascript. I've came across [this jQuery plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) online - it should do what you need.

```
$('#mydiv').columnize({ width: 200 , columns: 3 });
```

Answer (score 0):

usually, as alternative i use for older browser, is to set display:inline-block to childs with the width expected of columns , minus column-gap .

It change the layout going from left to right then, it draws a new line.

I'd rather use display than float, cause float elements can be hooked in middle, where inline-box just break the line and can be vertical-aligned to each other on a line.

If you really need to stack things from top to bottom columns by columns with no gaps , you can either adapt your script server to build your columns or use javascript.

Mansonry javascript could be be what you are looking for : http://masonry.desandro.com/